# How to generalize coordinate array into pixel-wide lines

Tags: c++, graphics

What I mean by the title is that I have an `std::vector` of a struct called Coord:

```
struct Coord
{
    int x;
    int y;
};
```

It contains the pixel coordinates that are a certain color on an image. Here they're colored blue (don't mind the red lines and text that is colored)
[image: Generated image]

I would want to remove pixels from that array so that we're left with only pixel-wide lines in the middle of the previous clusters of pixels. On this picture it would look something like this (my horrible sketch):
[image: Part of the picture]

---

Here is my function for finding the pixels:

```
std::vector<Coord> findPathIn(const std::vector< std::vector<Color> >& image, const Color& pathColor, double threshold)
{
    int maxError = ceil(threshold * 255.0);

    std::vector<Coord> path;

    for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
        {
            auto& current = image[x][y];
            if (abs(pathColor - current) <= maxError)
                path.push_back({ x, y });
        }
    }

    return path;
}
```

And the Color struct:

```
struct Color
{
private:
    friend int operator - (const Color& a, const Color& b);

public:
    int red;
    int green;
    int blue;
};

int operator - (const Color& a, const Color& b)
{
    int sum = 0;
    sum += a.red - b.red;
    sum += a.green - b.green;
    sum += a.blue - b.blue;

    int avg = int(sum / 3);

    return avg;
}
```

And to find the path in this image i used `findPathIn(image, { 0, 0, 0 }, 0.48)` where image is a 2d vector of Color. I'm using the STB library to read and write images.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is not working, or what is the question?

Comment: @acraig5075 My question is how to do it (erase pixels such that we're left with lines). I've been sitting on it for a few days now, and I can't figure out an algorithm for it.

Comment: I think you are looking for a *"skeletonisation"* algorithm. You can do it easily from the command-line with **ImageMagick**... https://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/morphology/#skeleton_info

Comment: See also `medial_axis` here... https://stackoverflow.com/a/58411378/2836621 and the other answer which uses OpenCV's `findContours()`.